# varchar vs nvarchar orderby linq to entities

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, sql-order-by

I have a database that has a table "Emails" field "Subject" of type varchar(200). When I order by in SQL:

```
select Subject from Emails order by Subject
```

I get results of:

1. 100-2-00000
2. 100000-1-00000
3. 1007-2-00000
4. 1007-2-00001
5. 1007-2-00002

I have a legacy desktop application that uses a third party grid, which uses .NET's string compare functions that give me the results in order of:

1. 100000-1-00000
2. 100-2-00000
3. 1007-2-00000
4. 1007-2-00001
5. 1007-2-00002

I have done some research into the difference, and this is likely because of the collation that the database is use. The .NET grid is using the string values as unicode while sql is not.

I tested out that casting the varchar(200) field to an nvarchar(200) field for ordering yields the same results:

```
select Subject from Emails order by cast(Subject as nvarchar(200))
```

1. 100000-1-00000
2. 100-2-00000
3. 1007-2-00000
4. 1007-2-00001
5. 1007-2-00002

I am making a web application that uses LINQ to replicate the ordering of the Emails that is displayed in the legacy grid. The order of the grid (having dozens of columns) can be established by users dynamically. I am creating dynamic lambda expressions to create a series of order by calls if there is ordering by multiple columns. My last obstacle for these queries is:

Is there a way to replicate the part `order by cast(Subject as nvarchar(200))` creating expressions in LINQ?

The current example of the orderby building is:

```
var query = (*/Working query*/)

var e = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Email), "e");
var param = Expression.PropertyOrField(e, "Subject");
var OrderParam = Expression.Lambda<Func<Email, string>>( param, e);
query.OrderBy(OrderParam);
```

This query returns the correct results in the order equal to `select Subject from Emails order by Subject`. But I would like them to match as if the Subject was an nvarchar.

I cannot control the collation directly in the database and I cannot change the type of the variable to be an nvarchar. I am using a legacy database has many more fields than just this one I am trying to order by.

Comment: I wish all new contributors would such good questions! I guess the difference is that the legacy grid didn't have paging so it could order the data *client-side*, whilst in web you do have paging and hence need the *database* to sort as unicode?

Comment: that is absolutely what im running into! I am paging 20 records at a time, so i need the base query to order. there could be thousands of records that i dont want to query for every record then sort then send back with skip/take calls on the query.

Comment: If you're using Entity Framework (and other ORMs likewise, I guess) it's not possible to add a collation or conversion phrase to an order by. The best you can get is trying to mimic linguistic sorting by removing "-" (and similar) characters before sorting, but that's still a long way from the very complex sorting rules that collations supply (like ignoring diacritics and other character similarities). An additional problem would be that a conversion before sorting would disable indexes as far as there are any. Maybe you really have to try and twist someone's arm and get the database modified.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view in the database and have Linq use the view instead of a direct table query. For instance:

```
create view v_emails as select cast(Subject as nvarchar) from Emails;
```

Next, update your entity model so that the view is available. This would allow you to sort by the subject column in nvarchar format without changing the datatype in the database.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am avoiding adding things like this, because i would need to add fields to the view for every new field that may be added to the Emails table in the future. Seeing as how there are already 40 fields in this table, of varying types, i would have to add casting for every varchar field.